# Python - next method not working properly with generator

Tags: python, iterator, yield

I made a class in python that splits a stream of code in tokens and advances token by token to work with them

```
import re

class Tokenizer:

    def __init__(self, input_file):
        self.in_file = input_file
        self.tokens = []
        self.current_token = None
        self.next_token = None
        self.line = 1

    def split_tokens(self):
        ''' Create a list with all the tokens of the input file '''
        self.tokens = re.findall("\w+|[{}()\[\].;,+\-*/&|<>=~\n]", self.in_file)

    def __iter__(self):
        for token in self.tokens:
            if token != '\n':
                yield token 
            else:
                self.line += 1

    def advance(self):
        self.current_token = self.next_token
        self.next_token = next(self.__iter__())
```

**After initialization:**

```
text = 'constructor SquareGame03 new()\n\
       {let square=square;\n\
       let direction=direction;\n\
       return square;\n\
       }'

t = Tokenizer(text)
t.split_tokens()
t.advance()
```

**It seems to work if i print the tokens**

```
print(t.current_token, t.next_token)
None constructor
```

**but every other call of the advance method give those results:**

```
t.advance()
print(t.current_token, t.next_token)
constructor constructor
t.advance()
print(t.current_token, t.next_token)
constructor constructor
```

So it's not advancing and i can't understand why.

Comment: Every call to `advance()` you are creating new generator from `__iter__()` which starts from beginning. So you get same results.

Comment: Oh thanks i think i fixed it. assigning the function iter to a variable ex. a = t.__iter__() and then using next(a) seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `.__iter__` is implemented as a *generator function* (instead of a *generator iterator*) which returns a *generator iterator*.

Every time `Tokenizer.advance` is called, **a new** *generator iterator* is created and returned by `.__iter__`. Instead, an iterator should be stored by a `Tokenizer` object at the initialization stage for all subsequent usage.

For example:

```py
import re

class Tokenizer:

    def __init__(self, input_file):
        self.in_file = input_file
        self.tokens = []
        self.current_token = None
        self.next_token = None
        self.line = 1

    def split_tokens(self):
        ''' Create a list with all the tokens of the input file '''
        self.tokens = re.findall("\w+|[{}()\[\].;,+\-*/&|<>=~\n]", self.in_file)
        self.iterator = self.__iter__()

    def __iter__(self):
        for token in self.tokens:
            if token != '\n':
                yield token 
            else:
                self.line += 1

    def advance(self):
        self.current_token = self.next_token
        self.next_token = next(self.iterator)
```

Another minimal example that may explain:

```py
def fib():
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while True:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a + b

# 1, 1, 2, ...
fibs = fib()
next(fibs)
next(fibs)
next(fibs)

# 1, 1, 1, ...
next(fib())
next(fib())
next(fib())
```

By the way, I cannot see the reason to mixed the usage of a `.__iter__` magic method and a separate `.advance` method. It might introduce some confusion.

Comment: Oh i understand, it was an easy fix thank you! Anyway the use of advance seems simple to me because it updates both the current and the next token. Do you have any optimization maybe?